# Custom page for list. Error "The attribute 'autoeventwireup' is not allowed in this page"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created custom new page item for list, [like this](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) . All was good, but then I changed master page and now when I open my custom new page, I getting error: "The attribute 'autoeventwireup' is not allowed in this page"

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the autoeventwireup attribute in your page declaration of your new masterpage.